# Basic question from quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy

Can a particle, having zero kinetic energy but with rest mass $m_0$ ($\sim E_0$) > V (V is potential energy), penetrate the potential wall V ?

Comment: one can try 'uncertainty principle'  to look at the possibility....

Comment: @drvrm Can you please elaborate?

Comment: user176263: the quantum particles are not  like  "classical ones"...therefore i think the uncertainty in its energy  and time can  be of the order of  Planck's constant  and if a large time interval is taken the particle can penetrate ....a similar example is alpha decay when the parent nucleus is at rest.

Comment: user176263 -i was thinking about the uncertainty in  energy related to time  and possibly if large time interval is taken the particle can  penetrate  .

Comment: @drvrm: Thanks for your comment. I was also thinking the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the mathematical formalism yes, it is called the [Klein paradox:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_paradox)

> In 1929, physicist Oskar Klein obtained a surprising result by applying the Dirac equation to the familiar problem of electron scattering from a potential barrier. In nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, electron tunneling into a barrier is observed, with exponential damping. However, Klein’s result showed that if the potential is of the order of the electron mass, V ∼ m c^ 2  the barrier is nearly transparent.

The difference comes because of special relativity, which the Dirac equation obeys.

Your special condition of the particle being at rest will have to address that a particle is never completely at rest due to the heisenberg uncertainty.